# How to ensure Stage opens as a window and not a tab?

Tags: java, javafx

New stages traditionally opened as new windows.Then MacOS came around and introduced this in (System Preferences -> General):
[image]

Now all my new JavaFX stages are all opening as new tabs on top of the first opened stage. If I change the system setting, stages once again open as windows. But I prefer to leave the system setting on "always" because its the only way pdfs and other documents will open in tabs. How can I override the system setting in my JavaFX apps and get my old windows back?

Comment: I do not use MacOS, but I would assume that is not possible as managing windows is the job of the OS, not your application. You overriding that would essentially be telling the user that you know better than them since they **chose** for the windows to be opened as tabs.

Comment: I made this [corresponding post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252490723?answerId=254696122022#254696122022) on the apple support forums asking how to manage tab/window behavior on an app-by-app basis. There, my first response was from VikingOSX who says "In the individual application if it was designed to allow that functionality" implying he has the polar opposite theory as you (that it is up to each application to manage this behavior on their own).

Comment: Additionally, in my JavaFX app, I use a Dialog. Dialogs are not documents, and of course, they are supposed to open as a popup window, right? But if you have the system setting in macOS set to "always", JavaFX Dialogs open in tabs.

Comment: So in order for my Dialogs to work correctly, I have to have the system setting on "never open tabs", which I don't want because I want my other applications to use tabs. Clearly, I must be missing something here.

Comment: Does changing the `StageStyle`, `Modality` or owner of you new `Stage` change anything? Maybe `initOwner(null)`?

Comment: @Matt If what trashgod suggests doesn't help then consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: @trashgod `initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY)` worked. Feel free to write that as an answer and I'll close this. Thanks!

Comment: I'll also write to the javafx mailing list to see if there's a better way since StageStyle.UTILITY has fewer features than a regular stage

Comment: @MattGroth: Excellent. Please don't hesitate to update my answer or add your own as new information arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New (possible) solution: Upgrade to JavaFX 17+7 or later.

After a few weeks they responded on the email list and integrated a change as can be seen [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/commit/58988582). I haven't fully tested it myself.

Comment: update: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx11u/commit/2808769f8533dc47adea1e5aa981ed08c0d729f8

Comment: Thanks for pursuing this. Can readers infer that this might be incorporated in JavaFX 11?

Comment: I do not know for sure. However, the commit message does say "Backport" and its on the "OpenJFX 11 Updates" repo.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354405/how-to-ensure-stage-opens-as-a-window-and-not-a-tab?noredirect=1#comment117319446_66354405), a [`Stage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) may have a specific `StageStyle`, `Modality` and owner. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354405/how-to-ensure-stage-opens-as-a-window-and-not-a-tab?noredirect=1#comment117352658_66354405), `StageStyle.UTILITY`, "a stage with a solid white background and minimal platform decorations," achieves the desired effect.

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY)
```

Comment: This is the most helpful answer. This does ensure the stage opens as a window and not a tab. However, it also removes the hide and fullscreen buttons from the windows title bar. I've contacted the JavaFX devs to see if there is a better solution and will update this with anything I learn.

Comment: @MattGroth: Thank you. This appears to be a macOS 11 Big Sur (v 10.16) [feature](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-tabs-in-windows-mchla4695cce/mac) Have you tried `StageStyle.UNIFIED`, which appears to be supported on macOS?

Comment: `StageStyle.UNIFIED` for me has the same behavior as not using `initStyle` at all. The Dialog window opens as a tab.